# ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved - Rails 3 seeding data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.2

I am using `rails 3.2.13` and `ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]` in `CentOS 5.6`. When I try to seed the data I got the following error.

```
** Execute Samp:seed:record_status
Creating RecordStatus: Active
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:105:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `block in save!'
/opt/Samp/lib/tasks/seed/record_status.rake:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/Samp/lib/tasks/seed/record_status.rake:16:in `each'
/opt/Samp/lib/tasks/seed/record_status.rake:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**record_status.rake**

```
16:  record_statuses.each do |rs|
17:       unless RecordStatus.find_by_seed_name(rs[:name])
18:       puts "Creating RecordStatus: #{rs[:name]}"
19:       RecordStatus.create!(:name        => rs[:name],
20:                             :seed_name   => rs[:name],
21:                             :description => rs[:description])
22:        end
23:     end
```

**EDIT-1**
****RecordStatus.rb****

```
class RecordStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_enumerated

 ACTIVE   = 1
 DISABLED = 2
 DELETED  = 3

  validates_uniqueness_of :id , :name
end
```

Comment: What kind of model validations do you have on the RecordStatus model??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3 doesn't support `create/alter/destroy instances` for enumerations by nature. If we wants to create any enumerations just add `Model.enumeration_model_updates_permitted = true` in `record_status.rake` file. REF : [Enumerations_mixin](https://github.com/protocool/enumerations_mixin)

Answer (score 0):

It appears like you must have duplicate names in your seed data. To find out for sure, change your call to `create!` to something like:

```
 rs = RecordStatus.new(...)
 unless rs.save
   raise "Couldn't save #{rs.inspect}: #{rs.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
 end
```